# Prove that for a cycle graph with $2n$ vertices, any set of $n+1$ vertices contains an adjacent pair?

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for a cycle graph with $2n$ vertices, any set of $n+1$ vertices contains an adjacent pair.

(It would seem to involve the pigeonhole principle…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one way would be to consider the n pidgeonholes:

$$ \{u_1,u_2 \} , \{u_3,u_4 \} , \cdots, \{u_{2n-1}, u_{2n} \} $$

Where the vertices are numbered as in the circle, ie $u_1$ is adjancent to $u_2 $ and $u_{2n}$ $u_2$ to $u_1,u_3$ and so on.

And the results follows.

Comment: There are $2n-1$ pigeonholes there. But how does the result follow?

Comment: Fixed it, mistake on the second one

Comment: Thanks, @SotArmen! That may be the best answer. Still curious if there are other ways of framing the proof.